Ask LLM to pick random data from prompted dataset
I try to generate suggestions of books. The problem is my LLM (here claude 3 api) give always the same well known books from one instance to an other...
So I have tried to give a [BOOKS DATASET] tag with a list of hundreds of books and I prompted the llm to take random books, but it keeps giving same well know books from the list again and again...
Any possibility to realy have random books ?

You might try to increase the temperature(closer to 1 for more variation) to induce variability in the response. But generally speaking if all you want is it to randomly select books wont a random() function suffice?
